# Check if object is in array in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a list of products in my Angular2 app. The user can click the product and the the product will be added to a selectedProducts array.

Now I want to highlight the selected products. How to do this? How can I check in the HTML if the current product (ngFor) is selected? The user can simply remove the product by clicking it again.

**Problem solved:**

```
*ngIf="addedProducts.indexOf(product) > -1"
```

Comment: Please share what you've done so far.

Comment: You can add a `selected` class once selected.

Comment: I think this is not the angular-way to do it. I want to solve it with Two-Way-Binding...

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of **[ngClass]** to highlight selected product as shown below,

Working Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/eB54ue72bj80dqqza6bQ

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <style>
    .active{
       background:red;
     }
   </style>

    <div>
      <div *ngFor="let product of products;let i=index" 
            (click)="click(i)" 
            [ngClass]="{active:i==selectedIndex}">  //<----[ngClass]

              {{i}}-{{product}}
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.products=['laptop','computer','keyboard'];
  }

  click(i){
    console.log(i);
    this.selectedIndex=i;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```